# How to fill a collection with randomly collected elements in limit of total weight?

Tags: algorithm, collections

I have 30 elements with different weight stored as number like 50, 100, 300 etc. After query received with "limit" argument, I need to response with array of randomly collected elements with sum of it weights, not above queried limit with some deviation allowed. As it's elements collected randomly, multiple variations for one query also allowed.

In examples I have deviation set to 30.

- Example 1, query for limit 560. I response it elements with weights 300, 150, 50, 40 in sum of 540.
- Example 2, query for limit 160. I response it elements with weights 150, 40 in sum of 190.

I don't know, may be there's some algorithm previously invented for such solutions? Or not and I must develop it by myself?

Thanks much

Comment: In example 2, suppose there was an element with value `160` as one of the 30 elements, what will you return?

Comment: @जलजनक I would like to return 160

Comment: [Knapsack Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) doesn't help?

Comment: Does the order matter in the collection you return? Is the goal to sample from collections that are as full as possible with some distribution (e.g. each one is equally likely), or is it okay if some items appear more than others?

Comment: @templatetypedef Order is not important, it's okay that some items can appear more than others